# JUnit Tests (Integrations Tests) only on local machine

Tags: java, junit

I've written a few db integration tests using latest JUnit version. I don't want the tests (annotated with @Test) to run on jenkins, but run it only on local. Is there are way to tell JUnit to run tests only if it indicates it's running within a special environment (locally)?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653066/exclude-some-junit-tests-from-automated-test-suite

Comment: Thanks. Didn't find this using the search. Recommend way for this? Deleting this question?