# JUnit - Ignore test when part of Suite

Tags: junit, junit4, test-suite

I am organizing some tests into suites, which is great, but I need to ignore the tests that are part of a suite so that my build doesn't run them automatically.

I can achieve that by excluding them from the build process, but wanted to see if JUnit supports that natively.

What is the cleanest way to achieve that?

EDIT:
In order to achieve that in a maven build I can categorize the tests (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14133020/819606) and exclude an entire category (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18678108/819606).

Comment: I am not aware of an easy built-in way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

***Junit4*** - You can try using

```
@Ignore 
public class IgnoreMe {
           @Test public void test1() { ... }
           @Test public void test2() { ... }
}
```

transformed to something like -

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses( {IgnoreMe.class, AnotherIgnored.class})
@Ignore
public class MyTestSuiteClass {
....
// include BeforeClass, AfterClass etc here
}
```

Source - [Ignore in Junit4](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html)

---

**Junit5**  - You can try something similar like -

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Disabled
class DisabledClassDemo {
    @Test
    void testWillBeSkipped() {
    }
}
```

Source - [Disabling Tests in Junit5](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-disabling)

along with suite implementation in Junit5 as

> If you have multiple test classes you can create a test suite as can
>   be seen in the following example.

```
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.runner.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectPackages("example")
@Disabled
public class JUnit4SuiteDemo {
}
```

> The JUnit4SuiteDemo will discover and run all tests in the example
>   package and its subpackages. By default, it will only include test
>   classes whose names match the pattern ^.*Tests?$.

where `@SelectPackages` specifies the names of packages to select when running a test suite via `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)`, so you can specify those which you want to execute OR those which you don't want to execute and mark them disabled as above.

Further reads - [@Select in Junit5](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/runner/package-summary.html) and [Running a Test Suite in Junit5](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner)

Comment: Is this answer still correct in the light of the now native implementation of suites in JUnit5?
Actually, specifying a suite with `@Suite` and `@SelectedPackages` adding `@Disabled` does not seem to have any effect.